# Add quarterly data in a list into a yearly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data set with quarterly data.

Example:
[2019, 1, 10, 20, 5],

```
[2019, 10, 56, 34],
[2019, 74, 66 ,32],
[2019, 20, 96, 31],
[2018, 13, 16, 35],
.....
```

I want to summarize and calculate the mean and find the max and min value (depending on the column) for each year and add the result to a new list.
column 1 -> mean, column 2, find max, column 3 find min;

```
[2019, 26.25,  96, 31]
[2018 .....]
...
```

I don't know how to approach this problem and I cannot use pandas or numpy

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following -

**METHOD 1: Using PANDAS**

```
#Mention all the columns and respective aggregations as key, value for a dict
g = {'var2':'mean', 'var3':'max', 'var4':'min'}


#Apply groupby with agg() using the above dict
df.groupby(['var1']).agg(g).reset_index()
```

Just replace the `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, `var4` with the actual variable names in the code.

```
   var1       var2  var3  var4
0  2018  13.000000    16    35
1  2019  34.666667    96    31
```

EDIT: If you are supposed to NOT use any pandas or numpy then I have to assume that your dataset is actually a list of lists and NOT a pandas dataframe else that would defeat the purpose. In that case you can use a list comprehension to solve this in the following way -

**METHOD 2: Using List Comprehension**

```
data = [[2019, 10, 56, 34],[2019, 74, 66 ,32],[2019, 20, 96, 31],[2018, 13, 16, 35], [2018, 14, 27, 33]]
```

```
#function to calculate average on a list
def average(lst): 
    return sum(lst) / len(lst)

#get set list of years
unique_years = set([i[0] for i in data])

[[[j[0] for j in data if j[0]==i][0],
   average([j[1] for j in data if j[0]==i]),
   max([j[2] for j in data if j[0]==i]),
   min([j[3] for j in data if j[0]==i])] for i in unique_years]
```

```
#output: [[2018, 13.5, 27, 33], [2019, 34.666666666666664, 96, 31]]
```

You can also do it with explicit for loops if you are not comfortable with List comprehensions -

**METHOD 3: Using explicit FOR - IF**

```
yr = []
v1 = []
v2 = []
v3 = []

#function to calculate average on a list
def average(lst): 
    return sum(lst) / len(lst)

#get set list of years
unique_years = set([i[0] for i in data])

for i in unique_years:
    for j in data:
        if j[0]==i:
            v1.append(j[1])
            v2.append(j[2])
            v3.append(j[3])
    yr.append([i,average(v1),max(v2), min(v3)])
    
print(yr)
```

```
#output: [[2018, 13.5, 27, 33], [2019, 26.2, 96, 31]]
```

Comment: They said "I cannot use pandas or numpy", and I'm sure they won't create their own dataframe structure

Comment: When you say 'they said', is this like an interview question? because this might not be the right place to ask it :)

Comment: Also, is your data in form of a pandas dataset or just a list of lists?

Comment: @Akshay_Sehgal It's not a question. It is a statement. They said that.

Comment: They = OP : *I don't know how to approach this problem and __I cannot use pandas or numpy__*

Comment: ah ok, apologies

Comment: Edited my answer to include the specific request

Answer (score 0):

create dict `d = {}` of form `year: [list, number of quartals]`

iterate over original list

```py
for yr, x,y,z in data: 
    if yr not in d:
        d[yr] = [[yr, x, y, z], 1]
    # now make changes
    else:
        a = d[yr]
        e, n = a
        e[1] += x
        e[2] = max(e[2], y)
        e[3] = min(e[3], z)
        a[1] += 1
```

now iterate through `d` again to divide `e[1] / a[1]` to get average
and put `e`'s in the result list